# How to install plugin manager and perfmon metric collector on remote server in Non- GUI mode?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, perfmon

I have installed `jmeter 5.2.1` on one of remote AWS server.

I want to collect summary report of response and server information as well with perfmon metric.

I have downloaded `jmeter-plugins-manager-1.6.jar` and `jmeter-plugins-perfmon-2.1.jar` and copied to /lib/ext

I then created a test script from jmeter on my local machine and copied to server and tried to run the same `jmeter -n -t AWS.jmx -l awsresults.jtl`

But I am getting an error as :

```
Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Problem loading XML from:'/root/apache-jmeter-5.2.1/bin/AWS.jmx'. 
Cause:
ClassNotFoundException: kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.CorrectedResultCollector

 Detail:com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: 
---- Debugging information ----
cause-exception     : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
cause-message       : kg/apc/jmeter/vizualizers/CorrectedResultCollector
first-jmeter-class  : org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService$XStreamWrapper$1.realClass(SaveService.java:98)
class               : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
required-type       : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree/kg.apc.jmeter.perfmon.PerfMonCollector
line number         : 219
version             : 5.2.1
```

When I run this on local machine in jmeter its working as expected.

Can someone please help me to understand and solve the error.?

Edit:

`

```
2021-03-01 09:23:36,931 INFO k.a.j.p.PerfMonCollector: PerfMon metrics will be stored in /tmp/perfmon_7034792572732251249.jtl
2021-03-01 09:23:36,931 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[StandardJMeterEngine,5,main]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kg/apc/perfmon/metrics/MetricParams
    at kg.apc.jmeter.perfmon.PerfMonCollector.initiateConnector(PerfMonCollector.java:200) ~[jmeter-plugins-perfmon-2.1.jar:?]
    at kg.apc.jmeter.perfmon.PerfMonCollector.initiateConnectors(PerfMonCollector.java:175) ~[jmeter-plugins-perfmon-2.1.jar:?]
    at kg.apc.jmeter.perfmon.PerfMonCollector.testStarted(PerfMonCollector.java:126) ~[jmeter-plugins-perfmon-2.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector.testStarted(ResultCollector.java:351) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
    at kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.CorrectedResultCollector.testStarted(CorrectedResultCollector.java:28) ~[jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter-0.4.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.notifyTestListenersOfStart(StandardJMeterEngine.java:206) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:381) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_282]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kg.apc.perfmon.metrics.MetricParams
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    ... 8 more
2021-03-01 09:23:36,937 INFO o.a.j.r.ResultCollector: Shutdown hook started
2021-03-01 09:23:36,937 INFO o.a.j.r.ResultCollector: Shutdown hook ended
```

`

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that you don't have the PerfMon plugin installed on your AWS instance, I don't think that the current version of JMeter Plugins Manager can detect/install the missing plugins in non-GUI mode so you will need to do this manually.

Something like:

1. Download [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/):

   ```
   wget https://jmeter-plugins.org/get/ -O /opt/apache-jmeter-5.2.1/lib/ext/jmeter-plugins-manager.jar
   ```
2. Download [JMeter Plugins Command Line Runner](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeterpluginscmd-command-line)

   ```
   wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/kg/apc/cmdrunner/2.2/cmdrunner-2.2.jar -P /opt/apache-jmeter-5.2.1/lib/
   ```
3. Install [JMeter Plugins Manager Command Line Utility](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManagerAutomated/):

   ```
   java -cp /opt/apache-jmeter-5.2.1/lib/ext/jmeter-plugins-manager.jar org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerCMDInstaller
   ```
4. Install the [PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/):

   ```
   /opt/apache-jmeter-5.2.1/bin/./PluginsManagerCMD.sh install jpgc-perfmon
   ```
5. That's it, now you should be able to execute your test

P.S. [According to JMeter Best Practices you should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.4.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-4-1-released-td5739226.html) or whatever its the [current JMeter latest stable version](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi)

Comment: Thank you.
Now earlier error is gone.However getting new error as :


Creating summariser <summary>
Created the tree successfully using /root/apache-jmeter-5.2.1/bin/AWS.jmx
Starting standalone test @ Mon Mar 01 09:23:36 UTC 2021 (1614590616582)
Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/HeapDump/ThreadDump message on port 4445
Uncaught Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kg/apc/perfmon/metrics/MetricParams in thread Thread[StandardJMeterEngine,5,main]. See log file for details.


I have updated question with log details .

Comment: Hello ,

I think I managed to solve above error with https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F-dHii9qZD0.